# Combining multiple tests in validating JSON content with jq

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq

I have following JSON object

```
{"color": "red", "shapes": [ "square", "triangle" ]}
```

I would like to validate the JSON object using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) using following conditions:

- *color* has value "red"
- *shapes* does not contain value "round"

The returned result should be either **true** or **false**.

I have 2 jq command which validate both conditions, but I'm not sure how to combine this into 1 expression:

```
json='{"color": "red", "shapes": [ "square", "triangle" ]}'
echo "$json" | jq '.["color"] | test("red")'
echo "$json" | jq 'any(.shapes[]; contains("round"))|not'
```

Any pointers or help would be appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, consider `jq <<<"$json"` rather than `echo "$json" | jq`, or -- if you want compatibility with POSIX sh without making your code needlessly fragile -- `printf '%s\n' "$json" | jq`. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html for the gritty details of the `echo` command, and the reasons to avoid it should be fairly obvious.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy interesting, tnx for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correct way to test a collection of conditions is using `and`.

In your case, a correct test would be:

```
(.color == "red") and (.shapes|index("round") == null)
```

Example (typescript):

```
jq '(.color == "red") and (.shapes|index("round") == null)'
{"color": "red", "shapes": [ "square", "triangle" ]}
true
```

In jq, `not` is a syntactically ordinary filter, so you could write the second condition as: `(.shapes | index("round") | not)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply verify that both tests return true with `all`:

```
echo '{"color": "red", "shapes": [ "square", "triangle" ]}' |
  jq '[(.["color"] | test("red")),
       (any(.shapes[]; contains("round"))|not)
      ] | all'
```

Create an array containing the results of each test, then pipe that array to `all`.

Comment: `contiains` might not be the best choice though. A simple equals might be better. Otherwise `"ground"` would fail.

Comment: I just copied the original, as I'm just showing how to consolidate the two tests into one call of `jq`.

Comment: This indeed answers the question correctly.  The answer is composed using the elements given which makes it correct answer.  Although, @peak's answer is how one should be constructing the expression in the first place and might be more educative for future readers.